# clang standard library bug or c++ undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, clang, std, undefined-behavior, compiler-bug

Does the following C++ program contain any ***undefined behavior***?

```
int
main()
{
        struct entry
        {
                uint32_t hash;
                uint32_t idx;
        };
        entry arr[31] = {
            {   7978558,  0}, {   9241630,  1}, {  65706826,  2},
            { 639636154,  3}, {1033996244,  4}, {1225598536,  5},
            {1231940272,  6}, {1252372402,  7}, {2019146042,  8},
            {1520971906,  9}, {1532931792, 10}, {1818609302, 11},
            {1971583702, 12}, {2116478830, 13}, { 883396844, 14},
            {1942092984, 15}, {1274626222, 16}, { 333950222, 17},
            {1265547464, 18}, { 965867746, 19}, {1471376532, 20},
            { 398997278, 21}, {1414926784, 22}, {1831587680, 23},
            { 813761492, 24}, { 138146428, 25}, { 337412092, 26},
            { 329155246, 27}, {  21320082, 28}, {1751867558, 29},
            {1155173784, 30},
        };

        std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
                  [](entry a, entry b) { return a.hash <= b.hash; });
}
```

When I compile with gnu c++ compiler or any clang/llvm after 12.0.0, the program works fine. However, when I compiled it with clang version 12.0.0 (the default compiler shipped on my Mac laptop), it crashed inside of `std::sort()` as following:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$ g++ -g -std=c++11 bug.cc
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Also if I change it to use std::vector instead of fixed size array. The std::sort() will never return when compiled with clang 12.0.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the comparator is not a strict weak ordering which violates the preconditions of `std::sort`, resulting in undefined behavior.

For two arguments `a` and `b` (possibly identical), a strict weak ordering `comp` should never evaluate both `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` to `true`. In other words, it should model the behavior of the built-in `<`, not `<=`.

So in your code it should be `<`, not `<=`, to make it a strict weak ordering.